# Can't use $elemMatch"

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mongodb, mern

When i am trying to hit the api for this part of code on postman i get error of Can't use $elemMatch I search but can't find any solution for that:-

```
  const accessChat = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;

  if (!userId) {
    return res.status(400).json({err:'UserId param not sent with request'});
  }

  var isChat = await Chat.find({
    isGroupChat: false,
    $and: [
      { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user._id } } },
      { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } },
    ],
  })
    .populate("users", "-password")
    .populate("latestMessage");

  isChat = await User.populate(isChat, {
    path: "latestMessage.sender",
    select: "name pic email",
  });

  if (isChat.length > 0) {
    res.send(isChat[0]);
  } else {
    var chatData = {
      chatName: "sender",
      isGroupChat: false,
      users: [req.user._id, userId],
    };

    try {
      const createdChat = await Chat.create(chatData);
      const FullChat = await Chat.findOne({ _id: createdChat._id }).populate(
        "users",
        "-password"
      );
      res.status(200).json(FullChat);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  }
});
```

Error image is attached
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXvTR.png

Comment: you need to tell us what is your schema structure

Comment: Can you post the `Chat` schema?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you need `$all` operator in your first query: `Chat.find({ isGroupChat: false, users: {$all: [req.user._id, userId]}})`. You'll avoid problems with `$elemMatch`.

Comment: const chatModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    chatName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    isGroupChat: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    users: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    latestMessage: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Message",
    },
    groupAdmin: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  { timeStamps: true }
);  

Charchit kapoor
Ipizzindev